# Sed for gzip files

Tags: command-line, sed, gzip

I have a bunch of gz files and unzipped version of them contains the patterns `A` and `B=1` (these are certainly on different lines where `A` appears first).

I want to write a command that gives me the content of lines where `A` is present and where `B=1` is present. Or at least the content between `A` and `B=1` inclusively.

Input file1 :

```
..A ...
...
...B=0..
...
```

Input file2 :

```
..A ...
...
...B=1..
...
```

**My command must** output `A ....B=1` for file2 and **nothing** for file1.

I did something like this, but is not working as expected:

```
find . -name \*.gz -print0 | xargs -0 zcat | sed -n -e '/A/,/B=1/p'
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Why not simply `zgrep`?

Comment: Because `zgrep` does not work on multiple lines.

Comment: So some lines contain A (you want those) and some lines contain `B=1` (you want those), some lines contain neither (you don't want those) and some lines contain both (you want those)? The pattern `/A/,/B=1/` says "find the first line that contains A and the first line after it that contains B=1 and *all* the lines in between - then start looking for A again".

Comment: All files will contain both `A` and `B=1`  or both `A` and `B=0` but `A` will be placed on some before line of `B=`. I want to print exactly these lines with `A` and `B=1`

Comment: `zgrep 'A\|B=1' *` shows "the content of lines where `A` is present and where `B=1` is present".

Comment: Take a look on a comment before `zgrep` will not do that for `A` and `B=1` because other files may contain `A` and `B=0` and not `A` and `B=1`

Comment: You'd do better to post sample input and desired output.

Comment: Ok, I did it. See above.

Comment: "My command must output A ....B=1 for file2 and nothing for file1." are you sure the number of dots are right ? Tbh, I still do not know if you want lines between or not or if you want any text on the line before `A`.

Comment: Dots mean that can be anything there. I want the text between `A` and `B=1` inclusively and only if `B=1`. For `A` and `B=0` output nothing.

Comment: Can `B=1` ever be before `A` ?

Comment: NO. Neither  `B=1` nor `B=0` can be before `A`.

Comment: I think the problem with your code is that it starts printing when it finds `A`, and it stops when it finds `B=1`. If it finds `A` it will start printing all lines, regardless of whether it is later followed by `B=1` or `B=0`. Is it possible to simply filter out files that have `B=0`, or is it more complicated than that? Do all files that have an `A` later have a `B=`? Do all files that have a `B=1` also have a `A` before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's ignore the compression for now. You want to output the lines between `A` and `B=1`, but only if both appear. The `sed` you used will not do that, since it starts outputting as soon as `A` is seen, and doesn't check for `B=1`. We could use the hold buffer in `sed` to keep everything until `B=1` is found, but I'm more comfortable with `awk`, so here:

```
$ echo -en 'not this\nA\nthis\nB=1\nnot this\n' | 
  awk '/A/ {save=1} save {data = data $0 ORS} /B=0/ {save=0; data=""}  /B=1/ {save=0; printf "%s", data; data=""} '
A
this
B=1
```

The `B=0` rule handles blocks that should not be printed.

Then, handling the compression and multiple files.
The `find`+`xargs` you did works, though if some files can have partial blocks (`A` without `B`), concatenating the files together will lead to problems. Assuming that's not the case, we can just stick the awk to the end:

```
$ find . -name foo\*.gz -print0 | xargs -0 zcat | \
  awk '/A/ {s=1} s {d = d $0 ORS} /B=0/ {s=0; d=""} 
  /B=1/ {s=0; printf "%s", d; d=""} '
```

If we do need to deal with partial blocks, we'll have to handle each file separately:

```
$ find . -name foo\*.gz -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c '
  for f; do zcat "$f" |  awk '\''/A/ {s=1} s {d = d $0 ORS} 
    /B=0/ {s=0; d=""} /B=1/ {s=0; printf "%s", d; d=""} '\''; done' sh
```

The quoting is horrible, so the `awk` script should probably to a file of its own.

Or just do it in the shell (Bash/ksh/zsh):

```
$ shopt -s globstar    # set -o globstar in ksh
$ for f in **/*.gz ; do zcat "$f" |
  awk '/A/ {s=1} s {d = d $0 ORS} /B=0/ {s=0; d=""} 
  /B=1/ {s=0; printf "%s", d; d=""} ' ; done
```

If you want to print only the intervening lines (not the `A` and `B=1` lines), exchange the positions of the `/A/ {...}` and `/B=.../ {...}` blocks.

Comment: That`s what I want. Thanks and well done.

Comment: @cehptr Of course, this would not work as intended e.g. if a file had `A` then `B=0` and the subsequent one had `A` and `B=1` (it'd print from the first `A` to `B=1`. I'd filter out files first to avoid this.

Comment: @simlev, oh dear, you're right. It doesn't work too well with the files concatenated.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly NOT the best way, but it works for me:

```
find -name "*.gz" | xargs zgrep -l A | xargs zgrep -l "B=1" | xargs zcat | sed -n '/A/,/B=1/p
```

First, we get a list of files, then we filter files containing A, then we filter files containing B=1, the resulting files we `zcat` to `sed`.

Danger: if one file contains both B=1 and A, in that order, the contents of that file is written to the end.

Example:

```
$ ls /tmp/file*gz
/tmp/filea.gz  /tmp/fileb.gz
$ zcat /tmp/filea.gz
one
two
three
A
four five
six
B=1
seven
eight
nine
$ zcat /tmp/fileb.gz
one
two
three
A
four five
six
B=0
seven
eight
nine
$ find /tmp -type f -name "file*.gz" | xargs zgrep -l A | xargs zgrep -l "B=1" | xargs zcat | sed -n '/A/,/B=1/p'
A
four five
six
B=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `pcregrep` and it has been built with libz support, you can do:

```
pcregrep --include='\.gz$' -rM '(?s)A.*?B=1' .
```

Example:

```
$ pcregrep --help | grep zlib
Files whose names end in .gz are read using zlib.
Files whose names end in .bz2 are read using bzlib2.
$ pcregrep --include='\.gz$' -rM '(?s)A.*?B=1' .
./1/2/3/x.gz:AAA
blih
BOB=123
./b.gz:A
blah
B=1
```

Comment: Cool! (+1) libz support is relevant! But: in my debian distribution the pcregrep has no support for gz/bz2 and recommends `zpcregrep`, which works fine `zpcregrep -M '(?s)A.*?B=1' *.gz` but has no option `--include` nor `-r`; in my fedora (pcre-tools with pcregrep  8.41 2017-07-05) -- no support for zlibs . Are compiling pcregrep locally?

Answer (score 0):

```
zcat *.gz | \
sed  's/B=[0-9].*/&\x00/'  | \
grep  -zo 'A.*B=1' | \
sed 's/\x00/\n=====\n/'
```

- line 1 (may be replaced by the find-command)
- line 2 adds a null after "B=..." lines to explicitly separate registers
- line 3 greps in a null-separated sequence of registers, the A...B=1 patterns
- line 4 (if useful) translate null to a more visible separator